# What is a friendly module that allows querying a MySQL database from Perl?

Tags: sql, perl, mysql

Searching CPAN yielded so many results I don't know where to start. I need a simple and friendly module for some basic querying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For raw SQL queries, you'll need [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/) and [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/). But I highly recommend that you also install and use [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/) - it'll make your life far easier.

Answer (score 3):

Main database module at CPAN is [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI). All other modules (except very little group) use DBI. DBI has drivers for databases. For MySQL it is called [DBD::mysql](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3amysql). With DBI you can write crossdatabase Perl code. Of course you will need to alter SQL code in case you are using DBMS-specific features.

P.S. And look at [placeholders](http://p3rl.org/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values).

Answer (score 0):

I use [DBIx::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aSimple) ..  it's not an ORM or anything, but does simplify SQL in perl a  bit with its into(), arrays() and hashes() methods.